# Excel VBA Copy / Paste throws Application Defined Error

Tags: vba, excel, paste, cut

This should be really basic but I've scoured the board for the past two hours and just cannot seem to figure out why this code block isn't working.

The idea behind it being the user has imported a comma-deliminated text file and due to the way the output is generated, some rows are shifted at a certain point. This code is supposed to loop through and shift those back.

```
    '' Check for any instances where columns have been shifted and reset data

For i = 2 To rowCnt

    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumnLast.Column + 1)) Then

        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumn0.Column + 1), Cells(i, findColumnLast.Column + 1)).Cut
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumn0.Column)).Paste

    End If
Next i
```

It works fine until it gets to this line:

```
Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumn0.Column)).Paste
```

where gives me an ambiguous error of "Application-defined or object-defined error." I even gave up and tried using the record macro feature to see if I was doing something seriously wrong and it gave me this:

```
Range("L199:V199").Select
Selection.Cut
Range("K199").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Is this a case of something not being qualified correctly, the range needing to be activated first, or what? For clarity, findColumn0 represents Column "K" and findColumnLast represents Column "U".

Thanks!

Edit:

Full (relevant) code:

```
rowCnt = Worksheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'' Locate the " Bureau Code" column
Set findColumnBureauCode = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Bureau Code"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'' Locate the " Program Code" column
Set findColumnProgramCode = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Program Code"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'' Locate the " Paid Expenditure" column
Set findColumnPaidExpenditure = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Paid Expenditure"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)


'' Check for any instances where columns have been shifted and reset data

For i = 2 To rowCnt

    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumnPaidExpenditure.Column + 1)) Then

        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumnBureauCode.Column + 1), Cells(i, findColumnPaidExpenditure.Column + 1)).Cut
        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumnBureauCode.Column)).Paste

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: What value does rowcnt have? Does the error occur on the first iteration of your loop, or later? Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: Try this `Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumn0.Column).Paste`.

Comment: rowCnt has a value of 4534, and it's stopping around row 199, which is the first instance where the export glitch occurs for this particular data set.

I did try Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumnBureauCode.Column).Paste and I got the error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: How do you declare `findColumnLast` and `findCOlumnBureauCode`? Those should be a `Range`, as you're using it.  Also, if you're using multiple worksheets, then you need to qualify `Cells()` with the sheet too. I.e. `Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumn0.Column)).Paste`  ...it looks like you're not including some relevant code, can you please edit and include it?

Comment: is there something different about the data set at row 199?

Comment: And what is the value of `findColumn0` ?

Comment: Would `Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumn0.Column).Address).Paste` work?

Comment: Export glitch? I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Scott, yes, the data set at row 199 is where the first "glitch" occurs that shifts several of the columns to the right by one. This code block is intended the look for them (as it does correctly right now) and shift them back by simple cut / paste

Comment: @ BruceWayne, I tried this: `Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumn0.Column)).Paste` and it still throws the error Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, I tried `Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumn0.Column).Paste' and it now gives me the error `Object doesn't support this property or method.'

Comment: I'm guessing that the import glitch has left the "empty" cells is a weird state. Can you do the copy/paste manually in Excel? You might try a .Clear method call before the .Paste.

Comment: @RichHolton, no, the import glitch is found quite easily using the `If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumnPaidExpenditure.Column + 1)) Then` line.

The entire purpose of this is to avoid doing the copy / paste manually, as it is just a small part of a greater part of the assignment from our client. What I can't get to work is the copy / paste

Comment: I'm wasn't suggesting that you should give up automating the process. I'm suggesting that you try to do it once manually in Excel to see if it works as expected there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is caused by the .Find method

Try using a function similar to this:

```
Public Function getColumnNumberFromColumnName( _
            ByRef ws As Worksheet, _
            ByVal headerString As String, _
            Optional ByVal hr As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim foundCel As Range
    Set foundCel = Nothing

    If hr > 0 Then
            Set foundCel = ws.UsedRange.Rows(hr).Find(What:=headerString, _
                                                      After:=ws.Cells(hr, 1), _
                                                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                      LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                      MatchCase:=True)
    End If

    If foundCel Is Nothing Then
        getColumnNumberFromColumnName = 0
    Else
        getColumnNumberFromColumnName = foundCel.Column
    End If
End Function
```

---

You could also eliminate the copy/paste actions by working with the range, similar to this (untested):

```
Dim tmpVals As Variant, colID As Long

With Sheets(1)

    For i = 2 To rowCnt

        col1 = getColumnNumberFromColumnName(Sheets(1), " Bureau Code", i)
        col2 = getColumnNumberFromColumnName(Sheets(1), " Paid Expenditure", i)

        If col1 > 0 And col2 > 0 Then

            tmpVals = .Range(.Cells(i, col1 + 1), .Cells(i, col2 + 1))

            .Range(.Cells(i, col1 + 1), .Cells(i, col2 + 1)).Clear

            .Range(.Cells(i, col1), .Cells(i, col2)) = tmpVals

        End If

    Next

End With
```

Comment: Thanks! I was having issues qualifying the .Range and .Cells, but is this faster than using cut / paste?

Comment: Yes, this should be faster than cut / paste (I haven't measured the speed but it would be very obvious when repeating it for thousands of rows)

Comment: Thanks! I added this in with the only modification being removing the "." in front of `.Cells` and it works much faster. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I worked on it a bit more and finally gave up looking for an eloquent way to go about it, but did finally get it to work:

```
rowCnt = Worksheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'' Locate the " Bureau Code" column
Set findColumnBureauCode = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Bureau Code"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'' Locate the " Program Code" column
Set findColumnProgramCode = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Program Code"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

'' Locate the " Paid Expenditure" column
Set findColumnPaidExpenditure = Rows(1).Find(what:=(" Paid Expenditure"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'' Check for any instances where columns have been shifted and reset data

For i = 2 To rowCnt

    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets(1).Cells(i, findColumnPaidExpenditure.Column + 1)) Then

        Sheets(1).Range(Cells(i, findColumnBureauCode.Column + 1), Cells(i, findColumnPaidExpenditure.Column + 1)).Cut
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, findColumnBureauCode.Column).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

Next i
```

Comment: If you're executing this code from Sheets(1) module you don't need to qualify the ranges but if you need to execute it from a generic module all ranges need to be qualified, like Scott and Bruce mentioned in their comments. 'Rows(1)' and 'Cells(...)' should be 'Sheets(1).Rows(1)' and 'Sheets(1).Cells(...)'